# Angular 6 - how to serve the dist folder generated with npm run build:ssr - on remote server

Tags: angular, remote-server, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I followed all the steps to install Universal and Server side rendering is working perfectly in local server. However when I moved dist to remote server, and tried serving with angular-http-server, the behaviour of SSR is lost.

[The image looks like a normal production build without SSR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6sH3.png)

Where as in my local when I served it using local.js (which I can't find in dist), the behaviour is SEO friendly.

Comment: You have use NodeJS with SSR for Angular

Comment: Check the terminal server side for any error